# How can i reach child node values of firebase realtime database in node.js?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to make push notifications in chat page of my application. So i am trying to make an rest-api for it.  I have a realtime database properties like this;

```
UserProfile 
  -->child (user id)
     --> Token : token.value
         UserName : username.value
```

So how can i reach token and username in node.js

I tried this but not reached child node value

```js
  var db = firebase.database().ref(`UserProfile`);
        db.once("value").then(function (snapshot) {
            $("#users").empty();

            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                snapshot.foreach(function (userSnapshot) {
                    var html = "<option value='";
                    html += userSnapshot.val().Token;
                    html += "'>";
                    html += userSnapshot.val().Username;
                    html += "</option>";

                    $("#users").append(html);
                });
            }


        });
```

I want to reach username and token values and actually id of every item of database. I want to add as a list. how can i reach them?

Comment: Your code looks valid at first glance. What's the problem with the code you shared? So when you step through it in a debugger, which line doesn't do what you expect it to do? Or alternatively: what specific part of your use-case isn't met by this code?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `Object.values()`:

```
db.once("value").then(function (snapshot) {
   Object.values(snapshot.val()); // Array of UserProfile child
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Object/values